# Symfony4 access RequestStack after kernel terminate

Tags: service, request, kernel, symfony4

I have a bunch of events triggered and dispatched to be handled after `KernelEvents::TERMINATE`. One of my services are dependent on details about the request and I therefor auto inject the RequestStack from Symfony. Sadly it seems that the request is not accessible after the kernel terminate. All functions like `getCurrentRequest`, `getMasterRequest` and `getParentRequest` return `null`.

I can extract the values I need and send them along in the event but that seems a bit excessive. Is there anyway I can have a service after kernel terminate that can access the request?

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: Sorry, no. But I havent tried the response from below.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean really "after terminate"? If you can include it "in terminate", it is quite easy - main php flow in index.php is following:

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
...
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

So even though `RequestStack` is already empty the original `$request` is still 'alive' during `kernel.terminate` event and more, it is in the event's argument - so it is easy to reuse it there, e.g.

```
public function onKernelTerminate(PostResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest());
}
```

Hope this helps at least other readers :-)